# How do I insert the buffer's name at the beginning of the buffer?

Tags: insert

I am trying to write a function that prints the name of the current buffer to the file in the current buffer in its first line. For example, if the file is called "test.el", when invoking such function, the result should be:

```
test.el
; rest of file
```

However, I am stuck with the following non-working function:

```el
(defun my-heading ()
  "Write the name of the present file on the first line."
  (append-to-file (point-min)   ; start: beginning of buffer
                  200           ; end: I don't know when to stop
                  (buffer-name) ; filename
))
```

Moreover, in the [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-to-Files.html) for the function `append-to-file`, it is written:

> Don’t use these functions [`append-to-file`and `write-region`] to write to files that are being visited; that could cause confusion in the mechanisms for visiting.

So, how can I write a function that appends text to the beginning of my current file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `insert` function will do what you want.  Below is a simple function that takes care of some housekeeping and inserts the buffer's name at the beginning of the buffer:

```el
(defun do-my-thing ()
  "Insert the name of the buffer at the beginning of the buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (insert (concat (buffer-name) "\n")))))
```